# Is there a term for a person who is half British and half East Asian?

Tags: terminology, cultural-phrases, social-interaction

I know quite a few people who have one parent from somewhere in the U.K. (generally England) and the other parent from somewhere is eastern Asia (China, Japan, South Korea, etc.). They are all very nice people, and I was just wondering, is there an ethnic term for people like this? (Please excuse the racism.)

If this is not the right site to post this question, please tell me what is.

Comment: An ethnic term is difficult to think of, because the kid might as well conform to one ethnicity. E.g. cheer for the English soccer team. Genetic/anthropological term could perhaps be East-Euroasian half blood.

Answer (score 1):

[Sino](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sino)-[Anglo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/anglo) is the term that comes to mind.  You could also say [Sino](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sino)-[British](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/british), but I more often hear the term Sino-Anglo.